# Port IIS 7 Setup to another machine

Tags: configuration, iis-7, installation, backup

What's the fastest and most efficient way of porting over an IIS setup on one machine to a blank IIS 7 install on another?

Including all the sites, applications, virtual directorys, ftp accounts, etc?

Thanks.

Comment: or should this go on serverfault?

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use this tool
   http://www.iis.net/extensions/WebDeploymentTool
   (it can even migrate between IIS6 and 7)
2. Alternatively you can do it manually:

http://iterat.ive.ly/index.php/2009/06/10/howto-export-iis7-configuration-to-another-webserver/

Comment: I like option 2 better. It seems more in line with the Microsoft-prescribed approach.

Comment: unfortunately copying the applicationHost config file results in 503 errors across otherwise working sites (even static html), and kills the app pool.  This seems to be a common problem

Comment: Please use this document to troubleshoot 503 errors.
http://mvolo.com/blogs/serverside/archive/2006/10/19/Where-did-my-IIS7-server-go_3F00_-Troubleshooting-_2200_service-unavailable_2200_-errors.aspx

Answer (score 1):

The Applicationhost.config xml file (%systemRoot%\system32\inetsrv\config\ApplicationHost.config) is the main configuration file of IIS 7.0, this configuration file contains all the information about sites, virtual directories, applications, application pools and global settings for the web server.

You can copy this file to the target server, or you may just be able to point both servers at the same file using symlinks, if they both have access to a shared filesystem.

i.e.

cmd /c mklink %systemRoot%\system32\inetsrv\config\ApplicationHost.config \server\share\config\ApplicationHost.common.config

I haven't done this, but [voices on the web seem to indicate this is possible](http://www.windowsnetworking.com/articles_tutorials/Introduction-Internet-Information-Services.html).

Also, if you want more control, consider using [Appcmd](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/114/getting-started-with-appcmdexe/).